# Sum/ subtract dynamic element by id using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have an order form where the user can add or remove tickets dynamically using ajax ( similar to railscast #197 where it's a nested form). Each ticket displays the ticket price (a ruby instance variable - @event.ticket_price) with a class of 'price'.

I found a snippet elsewhere which i adapted to sum the elements with class 'price' and display the result in a div with id 'total_price'

```
$('#total_price').html(function() {
var a = 0;
 $(".price").each(function() {
 a += parseInt($(this).html());
     });
return a;
 });
```

This generates the total price when an add ticket link is clicked but when the page loads initially it shows nothing (it should have the price of one ticket which is there by default). Also when a ticket is removed I need a function to subtract the price of that ticket from the total.
Lastly I would prefer the price to be in dollars but get a NaN when I do this, I guess I need a regex of some kind?

New to rails, newer to jquery, would appreciate some help with this, thanks!

the remove ticket function

```
    function remove_fields(link) {
  $(link).prev("input[type=hidden]").val("1");
  $(link).closest(".fields").hide();
}
```

the add ticket function

```
function add_fields(link, association, content) {
  var new_id = new Date().getTime();
  var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
  $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, I'm not sure about the structure of the rest of your code, but the price may not be appearing depending on when the javascript is executed. I suggest making a function named something like 'displayPrice' and pasting your code into there. Call the function when your button is clicked, and also call it when the body fully loads like so:

`<body onload="displayPrice()">`

For removing a ticket, you could remove the object with the class 'price' and then simply call the 'displayPrice' function again.

For the dollar sign, set the function to return as

```
return '$' + a
```

Javascript should handle the type conversion for you.

Comment: Instead of calling the function through onload, you should use the jQuery ready function. `$(displayPrice());`

Comment: Thanks @Clayton edited the question to include the relevant functions. Appreciate the answers still not sure what to do tbh. On the regex i was using the rails helper number_to_currency to render eg 10.5 as $10.50 for 'price' but this would then cause a NaN in the jquery function.

Comment: @Mick Ruane if each `.price` value has a $ symbol preceding it, you'll need to strip that out before attempting to parse the value. Try `$(this).html().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');`. Also if your values are not integers, you'll want to use `parseFloat()`.